# Веб-сервис с возможностью просмотра логов обращений

Tags: сервисы

Стоит задача: добавить в десктоп-приложение отслеживание статистики использования. Никакой информации передавать не нужно, просто при запуске отправить на сервер один пакет, чтобы потом, посмотрев логи, узнать сколько раз и когда была запущена программа.

Какой сервис посоветуете для этой цели? Упор на минимализм: получил символьное имя - смотришь логи.

Answer (score 1):

Поднять свой сервер, хоть бы и виртуальный, нагрузка будет минимальная в данном случае. nginx с его модулем [empty_gif](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEmptyGifModule) замечательно справятся. Вести лог обращений именно к этому URL в отдельном файле, считать строки.

С прицелом на будущее продумать механизм обновления приложения.